# Only getting a single element from a mapping function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am currently learning about mapping functions and have the following:

```
t = ['a','b','c']

def capitalize_all(t): 
    res = []
    for s in t:
        res.append(s.capitalize())
    return res

 capitalize_all(res)
 [A]
```

You can also use:

```
capitalize_all('b')
[B]
capitalize_all('c')
[C]
```

and etc. But my question is, why does this function only return one element in the list? Wouldn't res end up having three elements?

Comment: indentation is crucial in python and your `return` statement is one level too deep. Also list comprehension is the way to go in python: `return [s.capitalize() for s in t]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are returning from the function at the wrong place. What you are currently doing is making the first item in the list Uppercase, appending it to the new list and returning. Hence the result ends up with just one element. Change the return location as below and you'll have the desired output.

```js
t = ['a','b','c']

def capitalize_all(t): 
    res = []
    for s in t:
      res.append(s.capitalize())
    return res

print(capitalize_all(t))
```

Comment: This literally does the same thing.

Comment: No it does not. This returns all the elements in Uppercase format.

Comment: Thank you! I must have misread it the first time, that does work.

Answer (score 0):

please pay attention to the return sentence

```
def capitalize_all(t): 
    res = []
    for s in t:
        res.append(s.capitalize())
    #you should return res after for loop ends
    return res
```

Comment: I understand that, but unfortunately that does not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def capitalize_letters(letters):
    return [letter.upper() for letter in letters]
```